# How to transform a dataframe of tree data to identify plots that have been harvested between two intervals in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (`df1`) containing tree data, where each row represents a tree on a plot in different years. The dataframe has columns for plot ID (`plot`), tree ID (`tree`), information on whether the tree is dead (`dead`), whether it has been harvested (`harvest`), and the corresponding year (`year`).

I would like to transform this dataframe to create a new one (`df2`) that summarizes the information on a plot level, indicating whether a plot has been harvested between two specified intervals. The resulting dataframe (`df2`) should include columns for plot ID (`plot`), the start year of the interval (`year1`), the end year of the interval (`year2`), and a binary indicator for whether the plot was harvested within that interval (`harvest`).

I've provided sample input (`df1`) and the expected output (`df2`). Could someone please assist me in achieving this transformation using R or any relevant data manipulation techniques?

Thank you!

```
df1 <- structure(list(plot = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), tree = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), dead = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
    harvest = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), year = c(2000L, 2005L, 2010L, 2000L, 2005L, 
    2010L, 2002L, 2004L, 2002L, 2004L, 2006L, 2000L, 2005L, 2010L, 
    2010L, 2015L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L
))
```

And this is what I want to end up with:

```
df2 <- structure(list(plot = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), year1 = c(2000L, 
2005L, 2002L, 2004L, 2000L, 2005L, 2010L), year2 = c(2005L, 2010L, 
2004L, 2006L, 2005L, 2010L, 2015L), harvest = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: To me, your explanation sound like `df1 |> dplyr::summarise(year1 = min(year), year2 = max(year), .by = c(plot, harvest))`, but this does not match the expected output. What have you tried?

Comment: @Friede I tried using ```aggregate``` on ```plot``` level to calculate the ```mean``` of the ```harvest``` and then if it was higher than 0 I identified that there has been ```harvest``` on ```plot``` level and then trying tu use ```dcast``` to have the ```years``` as columns, but did not work also and it is a very dirty approach

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is **exactly** what you want, since I was not clear if you were analyzing at a plot-tree level or not. Assuming you are, this is what you do with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr) # version: 1.1.4

df2 <- df1 %>%
  # flag if there is a leading harvest or if the row is a harvest
  mutate(flag = if_else(lead(harvest) == 1 | harvest == 1, 1, 0)) %>%
  # bring the leading year to your row
  mutate(year2 = lead(year)) %>%
  # now set the harvest variable accordingly
  mutate(harvest = if_else(flag & lead(flag), 1, 0)) %>%
  # eliminate not needed rows
  filter(year < year2) %>%
  # select your columns
  select(plot, tree, year, year2, harvest)
  # group_by(plot, year, year2) %>%
  # slice(which.max(harvest)) %>% ungroup() %>%
  # select(plot, year, year2, harvest)
```

If you need an analysis at the plot level only, it is a small variant to this.

**Edits**: the last commented lines are the steps required in case your analysis is at the plot level.